# Skip xml atrributes only during deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-4.5

'[Serializable]

```
public class ABC
{
    public ABC()
    {
        this.AttributeList = new List<DEF>();
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool IsManual { get; set; }

    public List<DEF> AttributeList { get; set; }
}`
```

I need to skip some xml attributes during deserialization process. 
But they should be available while serialization.

I want all the attributes including AttributeList to be serialized. But during deserialization AttributeList must be ignored. Is it possible?
(I can't use [XMLIgnore].)

Comment: Can you please tell us what technology are you using ? Language at the least

Comment: Please provide more context: which programming language will you use to perform the serialization, what framework, etc?

Comment: I'm using c# with .net 4.5 in Visual studio 2013

Comment: Can you give an example - say a small piece of XML, and what you expect to be able to do with it?

Comment: I want the AttributeList to be serialized. But during deserialization it should ignore the AttributeList.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore a property during xml serialization but not during deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242320/ignore-a-property-during-xml-serialization-but-not-during-deserialization)

Comment: Is it possible using some customized class?

Comment: I want to suppress only deserialization of AttributeList but still be able to serialize it. If i use XmlIgnore property it will suppress the serialization also.

Comment: Using XmlIgnore its easy to ignore the property for both serialization and deserialization. But I want to ignore it only during deserialization.