# Deserialize a property, but do not serialize back again C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have an xml that contains certain information that was serialized in a certain version. Now in next version, I want that information to be deserialized, but dont serialize it back in the same property/element. That information will be handled in a child class and that will serialize it. I know I can use `XmlIgnore` but that will ignore both Serialization and deserialization.

P.S: I could make the string attributes null, but what about the doubles, int?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242320/ignore-a-property-during-xml-serialization-but-not-during-deserialization

Comment: not really. I did see this post before I asked this question. :)

Comment: If those, like mentioned by @JenishRabadiya don't help you, what is the issue? Seems like they answer your question (at least today). https://stackoverflow.com/a/22196341/586754 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9377646/586754 .